# how to handle namespaces in the root element

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I am reading from a csv file and transferring the data to an xml file using XmlSerializer in c#.But now I am facing a problem with the namespaces in the root element.My required xml should be in the following format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<abc:Country xmi:version="2.0" 
             xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns:abc="some url">
<Person></Person>
</abc:Country>
```

But I am getting my output in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<Country xmi:version="2.0" 
         xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Person></Person>
</Country>
```

I want the namespace of abc to be included in the root and then also "abc" should prefix only my root element i.e "Country". I tried using various options mentioned online but none of them actually worked for me.When i use the XmlSerializerNamespaces and overload my Serialiser class all opther namespaces disappear.So could you let me know how I could achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Is it important to use XmlSerializer? This sort of thing is pretty easy to do with XDocument instead. Something like this:

```
var document = new XDocument();
XNamespace abcns = "http://some/url/abc";
XNamespace xmins = "http://www.omg.org/XMI";
XNamespace xsins = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";


var element = new XElement(abcns + "Country",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "abc", abcns),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xmi", xmins),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsins),
    new XAttribute(xmins + "version", "2.0"),
    new XElement("Person"));
document.Add(element);
```

Comment: Yes using XmlSerializer makes it easy for my xml structure..I was able to figure out using namespaces with XmlSerializer

Comment: I'm not sure I follow or agree with your logic that the XML structure should be a deciding factor in which format you use. As you can see above, the same structure is relatively simple with XDocument as well, but there are other strengths and weaknesses to each approach. Either way, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following to include multiple namespaces in the root element of the xml:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("xmi", "http://www.omg.org/XMI");
            ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            ns.Add("abc", "some url");

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Country));
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml", true, Encoding.ASCII);
                serializer.Serialize(textWriter, country, ns);
```

"country" would be the object that you would be creating for the class "Country"(root element of your xml).